# $P(z)=4z^4+az^3+bz^2+cz+d$ where $0\le d\le c\le b\le a\le 4$ has a zero $z_0$ of magnitude $1$. Find the sum of $P(1)$s of all such polynomials $P$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Here's the problem statement:

> Consider all polynomials of a complex variable,
> $P(z)=4z^4+az^3+bz^2+cz+d$, where $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are integers, $0\le d\le c\le b\le a\le 4$, and the polynomial has a zero $z_0$ with
> $|z_0|=1.$ What is the sum of all values $P(1)$ over all the
> polynomials with these properties? (*2012 AMC 12B #23*)

In the solution, they state:

> $z_0 = 1$ is not a possible root. $z_0 = -1$ contributes 60 to the
> desired sum.
>
> Next, if $P(z)$ has no real root $z_0$ with $|z_0| = 1$, then $P(z)$
> must have a non-real root with $|z_0| = 1$. Because $P(z)$ has all
> real coefficients, it follows that the conjugate of this $z_0$ must be
> a root as well. Thus, $P(x)$ has a factor of the form $z^2 - 2ez + 1$,
> where $e$ is a real number with $|e| <= 1$.

I'm not quite getting the part about the reasoning behind the 'factor of the form' $z^2 - 2ez + 1$.
Could someone please explain, or offer an alternative solution?

Comment: You have that $z_0$ is a non-real root with $1=|z_0|^2=z_0\overline{z_0}$. Then $z_0$ is a root and so is $\overline{z_0}$. Therefore, your polynomial is divisible by $(z-z_0)(z-\overline{z_0})=z^2-(z_0+\overline{z_0})z+z_0\overline{z_0}=z^2-2\frac{z_0+\overline{z_0}}{2}z+1$. Put $e=\frac{z_0+\overline{z_0}}{2}$ and then $|e|\leq\frac{1}{2}(|z_0|+|\overline{z_0}|)\leq \frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1$.

Comment: The inequialities in the title and in the body are contradictory.